# swap dict items python

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I am trying to swap items by index inside one python dict,
here is my data structure

```
{'A': [4, 7], 'B': [5, 1], 'C': [0, 5], 'D': [1, 3], 'E': [3, 0], 'F': [2, 6], 'G': [7, 2], 'H': [6, 4]}
```

I want to swap items for example like this:

```
 {'F': [2, 6], 'B': [5, 1], 'C': [0, 5], 'D': [1, 3], 'E': [3, 0], 'A': [4, 7], 'G': [7, 2], 'H': [6, 4]}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You're going to need `OrderedDict`, because the regular dictionary type has no defined ordering.

Comment: What do you mean by "swap by _index_"? Dictionaries have *keys* and *values*.

Comment: Can you please give more details about when to swap?

Comment: It's entirely unclear what rules you're using here, but to be clear, while `dict`s are ordered in modern Python, they aren't sequences. To swap elements arbitrarily, you basically have to rebuild the `dict` from scratch in the new order, usually easiest if you convert to a sequence (e.g. `list(mydict.items())`), perform the necessary swaps, then convert the `list` back to a `dict`.

Comment: @Alexander Dictionaries are insertion-ordered starting with Python 3.7.

Comment: @Alexander: `dict`s have defined ordering (insertion order) in 3.7+ (3.6+ for CPython and PyPy as an implementation detail). `OrderedDict` lets you move items to the front or back of the order without rebuilding from scratch, explicitly pop from either end, and compare in an order-sensitive manner, but the plain `dict` is ordered already.

Comment: Are they the same just in a different order? Even if dictionaries keep there insertion order in recent Python versions, it is still better to not rely on their order. If you really need order, use an `OrderedDict` or a `list`.

Comment: i use list cmd but only swap values not keys

Comment: indexA, indexB = (random.sample(range(len(population)), 2))
        population[genes[indexA]], population[genes[indexB]] = population[genes[indexB]], population[genes[indexA]]
this is my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reorder a `dict` arbitrarily without rebuilding it (a bunch of targeted `pop`s and reinsertions could do it piece by piece, but it would be absurdly complicated to little or no benefit). If you want to swap the position of two `key/value` pairs, your best option is to convert to a `list` of such pairs, swap the indices, then convert back to `dict`, e.g.:

```
population = {'A': [4, 7], 'B': [5, 1], 'C': [0, 5], 'D': [1, 3], 'E': [3, 0], 'F': [2, 6], 'G': [7, 2], 'H': [6, 4]}
population = list(population.items())
population[indexA], population[indexB] = population[indexB], population[indexA]
population = dict(population)
```

This is `O(n)` work to be clear (done once to convert to `list`, again to convert back to `dict`); if you actually need to do it repeatedly, I'd suggest sticking to a `list` without converting to a `dict` at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the dict to a list first:

```
d = {'A': [4, 7], 'B': [5, 1], 'C': [0, 5], 'D': [1, 3], 'E': [3, 0], 'F': [2, 6], 'G': [7, 2], 'H': [6, 4]}
l = list(d.items())
l[i1], l[i2] = l[i2], l[i1]
d = dict(l)
```

Comment: @Fardin: The original answer used `.values()` by mistake; it's been edited to use `.items()` which fixes the problem.